# How do I copy a group layer set from one file to another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

How do I copy a group layer set from one file to another?

I.e.: If I have a layer group in one file and want it in another file, how can I copy the layer group to another open Photoshop file? Also, does your solution work fine for individual layers (inc, layer, styles, masks, etc., etc.)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Layers and layer groups

1. Make sure you can see the canvas of both the source and destination images.
2. On the source image, grab that layer or layer group and drag it over to the destination image.
3. As you're doing this, the whole destination canvas will sport a black border. This shows that you're about to drop in a layer (or layer group) into that image.
4. Release and you're done.

#### Layer styles

If you're doing this with a layer style, remember that the last selected layer of the destination is where the layer style will end up.

#### Layer masks

The above drag-and-drop method will not work with layer masks. They come with the entire layer or not at all.

Comment: nice thanks! Seems obvious now but I couldnt find it at the time!

Comment: not obvious at all. there should be a copy/paste command.

Answer (score 7):

Select the layers or the layer group you wish to copy and right click, then click duplicate.

In the modal box that comes up there is a dropdown option called 'Document'.

Use the dropdown menu to select the destination file you want to copy the layers or layer group to.

Also, if you have the correct layer or layer group selected in the destination document, the layers will be copied to that position.

Doing the above ensures that the layers or layer group will be placed in the exact same position in the destination document.

Comment: I find this to be a much better answer, thank you for this.

Answer (score 3):

Layers and layer groups

Make sure you can see the canvas of both the source and destination images.

On the source image, grab that layer or layer group and drag it over to the destination image.

As you're doing this, the whole destination canvas will sport a black border. This shows that you're about to drop in a layer (or layer group) into that image.

Release and you're done.

Layer styles

If you're doing this with a layer style, remember that the last selected layer of the destination is where the layer style will end up.

Layer masks

The above drag-and-drop method will not work with layer masks. They come with the entire layer or not at all.